# Dividir acessos entre o novo site e o antigo

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, servidor

Vou publicar um novo site e queria que apenas alguns acessos fossem para ele para que eu possa avaliar seu funcionamento e os outros acessos serão encaminhados para o atual site.
O Facebook faz algo semelhante quando lança uma nova interface.
O servidor é Windows Server 2008.
Alguém já fez isso ou tem alguma ideia de como pode ser feito?

Farei isso no servidor onde está a aplicação

Comment: Estamos falando de quais acessos? Do banco de dados? Da sua aplicação? Pode editar sua pergunta e fornecer mais detalhes?

Comment: É só no servidor onde está a aplicação